# Sinatra execute code before uploading

Tags: forms, file, post, upload, sinatra

I'm having a simple HTML form on my page that looks like this:

```
<form action="/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="input" name="pin" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Now what I am trying to accomplish (with Sinatra) is to check if the PIN entered into the form field is correct:

```
post "/" do
    if params[:pin] == "1234"
        start_upload()
    else
        print_error_message()
    end
end
```

Of course, I want the PIN to be checked before the file starts uploading. But that's my problem. Immediately after clicking the "Upload" button, the file upload starts until it is finished. Then the script checks to see if the PIN is valid.

Is there a way to do stuff before the file upload starts? And if not, what other ways of doing this are there?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you use some Ajax and split up your request this won't work. You could have two forms, one that holds the pin and that authorizes the user. Once you enter a correct pin you send an asyn request to the server which will then reply with a positive or a negative answer. Depending on the response some javascript will then enable your file upload button so you can start uploading the file. What you should also do is setting a session for the user so that only an authorized user (via the pin) is allowed to send a form. If you check the Sinatra Readme you can find some information on how to do that.

That would be my solution.